# Куча была повреждена

Tags: c++, строки, указатели, память

При компилировании выдает ошибку 
Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x77C7F94D (ntdll.dll) в test2.exe: 0xC0000374: Куча была повреждена (параметры: 0x77CBB960).
Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x77C7F94D (ntdll.dll) в test2.exe: 0xC0000374: Куча была повреждена (параметры: 0x77CBB960).
Я понимаю что ошибка в функции strcat, но не могу понять по чему

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const char* Path = "D:\\SQLite\\";
    char oldname[] = "1.txt";
    char newname[] = "2.txt";
    const char* NewPath = "D:\\";
    char* Files = new char[strlen(Path) + strlen(oldname)+1];
    strcat(Files, Path);
    strcat(Files, oldname);
    cout<<Files;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А теперь еще раз - точно **при компилировании**?

Comment: Оффтоп, если использовать `std::string`, можно использовать `+` для сложения: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15319868/5909792 :)

Comment: В проекте есть функции которые работают только с переменными char, и переводить их туда обратно не хотелось бы.

Comment: Да не правильно выразился, при отладке проект выдает ошибку

Answer (score 4):

Итак, поехали. Не компилировать, а выполнять.

```
char* Files = new char[strlen(Path) + strlen(oldname)+1];
```

Без проблем, менеджер памяти выделил место в памяти и отдал его вам. Само собой, никак его не чистя (вы же не говорили, что его надо инициализировать?). И там лежит, например, что-то вроде

```
asdgysyh782qy6yr76786bxstgq748qs67576529187%*^%$@!VFGG&%&T#@
```

Словом мусор. К которому вы **ДОБАВЛЯЕТЕ** свою строку. Приписываете ее в конец. Который может оказаться далеко за пределами выделенной памяти:

```
strcat(Files, Path);
```

Почему бы вам не **СКОПИРОВАТЬ** первую часть новой строки?

```
strcpy(Files, Path);
```

Вопрос не риторический - мне действительно интересно, неужели там, откуда вы узнали о `strcat` (на лекции, из книги...) ничего не было сказано сначала о `strcpy`?

Comment: ... или вообше  о том, что делает   strcat